# Slick Slider Jumping on navigation - Variable width and Center mode

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have an issue with my use if slick (slider http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

I have a custom design and it is implemented but there is a strange jumping when the slider is moved to the next. See Demo  here -http://yourwebsitedemo.eu/sgslider/

Included is Bootstrap, jQuery and Slick

HTML/CSS are validated - No errors

My Code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#carousel').slick({
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      centerMode: true,
      variableWidth: true,
      centerPadding: '0px',
                cssEase: 'ease'
  });
 $("div.slick-list").removeAttr( 'style' );
 // Previous
 $("button.slick-prev").empty();
 $("button.slick-prev").append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left circle circle-left"></i>');
 // // Next
 $("button.slick-next").empty();
 $("button.slick-next").append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right circle circle-right"></i>');
});
```

```css
/*===================
        Fonts Style
===================*/
@font-face {
 font-family: 'nexa_rust_sansblack_01';
 src: url('../fonts/nexarustsans-black01-webfont.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/nexarustsans-black01-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/nexarustsans-black01-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/nexarustsans-black01-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/nexarustsans-black01-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/nexarustsans-black01-webfont.svg#nexa_rust_sansblack_01') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'nexa_boldregular';
 src: url('../fonts/nexa_bold-webfont.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/nexa_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/nexa_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/nexa_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/nexa_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/nexa_bold-webfont.svg#nexa_boldregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'droid_serifbold';
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-webfont.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-webfont.svg#droid_serifbold') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'droid_serifbold_italic';
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-bolditalic-webfont.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-bolditalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bolditalic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bolditalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bolditalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-bolditalic-webfont.svg#droid_serifbold_italic') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'droid_serifitalic';
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-italic-webfont.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/droidserif-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/droidserif-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-italic-webfont.svg#droid_serifitalic') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'droid_serifregular';
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.svg#droid_serifregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
html {
 font-size: 16px;
}
body {
 background: #fff;
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'nexa_rust_sansblack_01', Helvetica, arial;
 font-size: 3.75rem;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'nexa_rust_sansblack_01', Helvetica, arial;
 font-size: 1.5rem; /*24px*/
 line-height: 2.125rem; /* 34px */
}
h3 {
 font-family: 'nexa_boldregular';
 font-size: 32px;
 line-height: 45px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
}
h4 {
}
h5 {
}
h6 {
}
p {
 font-family: 'droid_serifregular', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 line-height: 1.9375rem; /*15px*/
}
*:focus { outline: none; }
.no-pad-left {
 padding-left: 0;
}
.no-pad-right {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.no-pad-lr {
 padding: 0;
}
.carousel {
 height: 530px;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: auto;
}
button.slick-prev {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 42%;
 left: 20%;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
}
button.slick-next {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 42%;
 left: 75.5%;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
}
.sm-slide-img {
 border: none;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 1px;
}
.sm-slide-img img {
 height: 460px;
 padding: 20px 0;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.slick-center img {
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.slick-center .slide-text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 padding: 100px 60px 110px 60px;
 margin-top: -66%;
}
.slick-slide:focus {
 display: block;
}
.slick-center .slide-text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 padding: 100px 60px 68px 60px;
 margin-top: -62.5%;
}
.slide-text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0%;
 right: 10%;
 border: none;
 padding: 72px 60px 110px 60px;
 margin-top: -65%;
}
.slide-text h1 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.slide-text p {
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: 'nexa_boldregular';
 line-height: 50px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}
.slide-text p span, .slide-text p span:before, .slide-text p span:after {
 text-decoration: underline;
 border: none !important;
}
img.slide-bow-icon {
 width: 37px;
 height: 17px;
 margin: 5px auto;
 padding: 0px 0px;
}
.slick-center img.slide-bow-icon {
 width: 37px;
 height: 17px;
 margin: 25px auto;
 padding: 0;
}
.icon-lines {
 line-height: 1.5rem;
 text-align: center;
}
.icon-lines span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
.icon-lines span:before, .icon-lines span:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 height: 11px; /*border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;*/
 border-top: 2px solid #fff;
 top: 47%;
 width: 30px;
 vertical-align: -50%;
}
.icon-lines span:before {
 right: 115%; /*margin-right: 15px;*/
}
.icon-lines span:after {
 left: 115%; /*margin-left: 15px;*/
}
.circle-left {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 padding: 18px 22px 18px 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;*/
 /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888; */
 /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.circle-right {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 padding: 18px 20px 18px 22px;
 display: inline-block;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;*/
 /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888; */
 /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.circle:hover, .circle:focus {
 color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.tint {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-center .tint:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
 -o-transition: all .2s ease;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}
.tint:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 20px 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
 -o-transition: all .2s ease;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}
.tint:hover:before {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>SM Slider</title>

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Slick Slide -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css"/>
  <!-- Slider Style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 class="text-center">Slider for Smart Groom</h1>
  
  <div class="container-fluid no-pad-lr">

   <div id="carousel" class="carousel">

     <div class="sm-slide-img">
      <figure class="tint"><img src="img/tux-or-suit.png" alt=""></figure>
      <div class="slide-text icon-lines">
       <h3>What to wear on your wedding day: Tux or Suit?</h3>
       <span><img class="slide-bow-icon" src="img/icon-slider.png" alt="" width="70" height="33"></span>
       <p>27 sep // in <span>style</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="sm-slide-img icon-lines">
      <figure class="tint"><img src="img/tuxedo.png" alt=""></figure>
      <div class="slide-text">
       <h3>What to wear on your wedding day: Tux or Suit?</h3>
       <span><img class="slide-bow-icon" src="img/icon-slider.png" alt="" width="70" height="33"></span>
       <p>27 sep // in <span>style</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="sm-slide-img icon-lines">
      <figure class="tint"><img src="img/suits.png" alt=""></figure>
      <div class="slide-text">
       <h3>What to wear on your wedding day: Tux or Suit?</h3>
       <span><img class="slide-bow-icon" src="img/icon-slider.png" alt="" width="70" height="33"></span>
       <p>27 sep // in <span>style</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="sm-slide-img">
      <figure class="tint"><img src="img/tux-or-suit.png" alt=""></figure>
      <div class="slide-text icon-lines">
       <h3>What to wear on your wedding day: Tux or Suit?</h3>
       <span><img class="slide-bow-icon" src="img/icon-slider.png" alt="" width="70" height="33"></span>
       <p>27 sep // in <span>style</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="sm-slide-img icon-lines">
      <figure class="tint"><img src="img/tuxedo.png" alt=""></figure>
      <div class="slide-text">
       <h3>What to wear on your wedding day: Tux or Suit?</h3>
       <span><img class="slide-bow-icon" src="img/icon-slider.png" alt="" width="70" height="33"></span>
       <p>27 sep // in <span>style</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="sm-slide-img icon-lines">
      <figure class="tint"><img src="img/suits.png" alt=""></figure>
      <div class="slide-text">
       <h3>What to wear on your wedding day: Tux or Suit?</h3>
       <span><img class="slide-bow-icon" src="img/icon-slider.png" alt="" width="70" height="33"></span>
       <p>27 sep // in <span>style</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>

     

   </div>

  </div>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Slick Nav -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Slider JS -->
  <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you find solution? Now I have similar problem I think (because demo not work now).

Comment: Hello Dmitriy, i cant remember the solution but I found that insuring my images where loaded with the slick on init function it caused the jumping to stop. Maybe include a jsfiddle to see your issue. (working slide in the end http://smartgroom.com/)

Comment: The URL for your demo is 404ing

Answer (score 0):

Please check it. I remove transition from css.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#carousel').slick({
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      centerMode: true,
      variableWidth: true,
      centerPadding: '0px',
                cssEase: 'ease'
  });
 $("div.slick-list").removeAttr( 'style' );
 // Previous
 $("button.slick-prev").empty();
 $("button.slick-prev").append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left circle circle-left"></i>');
 // // Next
 $("button.slick-next").empty();
 $("button.slick-next").append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right circle circle-right"></i>');
});
```

```css
html {
 font-size: 16px;
}
body {
 background: #fff;
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'nexa_rust_sansblack_01', Helvetica, arial;
 font-size: 3.75rem;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'nexa_rust_sansblack_01', Helvetica, arial;
 font-size: 1.5rem; /*24px*/
 line-height: 2.125rem; /* 34px */
}
h3 {
 font-family: 'nexa_boldregular';
 font-size: 32px;
 line-height: 45px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
}
h4 {
}
h5 {
}
h6 {
}
p {
 font-family: 'droid_serifregular', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 line-height: 1.9375rem; /*15px*/
}
*:focus { outline: none; }
.no-pad-left {
 padding-left: 0;
}
.no-pad-right {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.no-pad-lr {
 padding: 0;
}
.carousel {
 height: 530px;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: auto;
}
button.slick-prev {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 42%;
 left: 20%;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
}
button.slick-next {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 42%;
 left: 75.5%;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
}
.sm-slide-img {
 border: none;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 1px;
}
.sm-slide-img img {
 height: 460px;
 padding: 20px 0;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.slick-center img {
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding: 0;

}
.slick-center .slide-text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 padding: 100px 60px 110px 60px;
 margin-top: -66%;
}
.slick-slide:focus {
 display: block;
}
.slick-center .slide-text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 padding: 100px 60px 68px 60px;
 margin-top: -62.5%;
}
.slide-text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0%;
 right: 10%;
 border: none;
 padding: 72px 60px 110px 60px;
 margin-top: -65%;
}
.slide-text h1 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.slide-text p {
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: 'nexa_boldregular';
 line-height: 50px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}
.slide-text p span, .slide-text p span:before, .slide-text p span:after {
 text-decoration: underline;
 border: none !important;
}
img.slide-bow-icon {
 width: 37px;
 height: 17px;
 margin: 5px auto;
 padding: 0px 0px;
}
.slick-center img.slide-bow-icon {
 width: 37px;
 height: 17px;
 margin: 25px auto;
 padding: 0;
}
.icon-lines {
 line-height: 1.5rem;
 text-align: center;
}
.icon-lines span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
.icon-lines span:before, .icon-lines span:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 height: 11px; /*border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;*/
 border-top: 2px solid #fff;
 top: 47%;
 width: 30px;
 vertical-align: -50%;
}
.icon-lines span:before {
 right: 115%; /*margin-right: 15px;*/
}
.icon-lines span:after {
 left: 115%; /*margin-left: 15px;*/
}
.circle-left {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 padding: 18px 22px 18px 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;*/
 /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888; */
 /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.circle-right {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 padding: 18px 20px 18px 22px;
 display: inline-block;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;*/
 /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888; */
 /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff; */
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.circle:hover, .circle:focus {
 color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.tint {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-center .tint:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 
}
.tint:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 20px 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);

}
.tint:hover:before {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```

```html
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Slick Slide -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css"/>
    
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Slick Nav -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
    
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid no-pad-lr" style="background:#333;">

   <div id="carousel" class="carousel">

     <div class="sm-slide-img">
      <figure class="tint"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt=""></figure>
      
                        
     </div>

     <div class="sm-slide-img icon-lines">
      
                        <figure class="tint"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt=""></figure>
     </div>

     <div class="sm-slide-img icon-lines">
      
                        <figure class="tint"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt=""></figure>
     </div>
     <div class="sm-slide-img">
      
                        <figure class="tint"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt=""></figure>
     </div>

     
                    

     
                    

     

   </div>

  </div>
```